# Command ping -c 1 localhost requires admin EVEN if run as admin

Tags: windows-8, command-line, ping, administrator

I've written a program that makes ip addresses, and I'm trying to ping the IP addresses to find out if they are false or true.

When I use the command

```
ping -c 1 <ip>
```

it tells me

> Access denied. Option -c requires administrative privileges.

Now I get that, run it as admin, so now I run the same command from an admin prompt it tells me

> Access denied. Option -c requires administrative privileges.

Alright now I'm confused,does anyone have any idea what I need to do?

Pictures or it didn't happen:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just curious, and I may be wrong, but why are you using the -c option? Did you mean to use -n for counts?

Answer (score 0):

#### Does anyone have any idea what I need to do?

The command shell running `ping` needs to have system account permissions.

1. Download and install [psexec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) from [SysInternals](http://www.sysinternals.com/).
2. Open a Command Prompt with administrator privileges.
3. Run

   ```
   psexec -i -s -d cmd.exe
   ```

   where

   - `-d` is don't wait for process to terminate (non-interactive).
   - `-i` is run the program so that it interacts with the desktop of the specified session on the remote system. If no session is specified the process runs in the console session.
   - `-s` is run the remote process in the System account.
4. In the new `cmd` shell you can now run `ping -c`

   ```
   ping –c <interface number> google.com
   ```

Source [Access denied on ping -c command in Administrator cmd](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d8d5eff3-f749-463e-8a5a-27af70942ea5/access-denied-on-ping-c-command-in-administrator-cmd?forum=w8itpronetworking)

Comment: Why does it not allow me? I've checked the read an execute information, it says I have system access, so I guess I'm confused?

Comment: **System access** is not the same as running under the **System Account**.